# Application with 2 Activities Running Parallel

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an application that uses 2 activities, when clicking item in a listview inside Activity 1 it goes to Activity 2 and adds new fragment to it, and pressing the back button it goes back to Activity 1, but Activity 2 and all fragments/controls are destroyed, and clicking another item in Activity 1, it creates new Activity 2 and adds fragment to it.

is there anyway i can run the 2 activities in parallel? so both are running in parallel?
i use this code to start Activity 2

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayDataActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

can i keep reference to something in Activity 1 so clicking on listview items shows activity 2 if it's already created?

thanks

Comment: Are you calling activity.finish() on back button click in activity 2,if so then then do not finish activity2 on back button click?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why do you need that. Check your app architecture and/or UI - it is possibly wrong.

But it is possible - you need to maintain 2 activity tasks ([google documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html))

- Use different `taskAffinity` for your activities to create two tasks (separate activity stacks)
- Override onBack button if you need it - replace with appropriate second activity Intent call

Comment: second activity contains fragments with lots of data, re-instantiating all those fragments and data inside will take a lot of time, so each time user chooses new topic, i want previous topics to be there without re-instantiating.

Comment: @user3489771 use 2 fragments for that in ONE Activity. No need to have 2

Answer (score 0):

You have two choises:

1) Like Dmitry stated - use two different tasks for the activities.

2) instead of creating activity2 just maintain fragment stack and create and push fragment2 to it.

For implementation of 2 you'll have to extend FragmentActivity and create and manipulate the fragment stack yourself

Comment: can a Fragment have sub-fragments?

Comment: yes but it wasn't my point. You should create a FragmentActivity, in that activity to maintain a fragment stack, and to add/remove fragments from it

Comment: yes, i did so, but moving away from this activity kills all fragments inside it, and all fragments must be recreated again